# AccessibilityService Listview item click or Analog enter event？

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to traverse the ListView, to implement the click event to each item, but does not work.
please Why clicking has no effect?

```
public void addFriendSearch(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {

        try {


                L.i(TAG, "-addFriendSearch-parent widget----------------------------" + info.getClassName());
                L.i(TAG, "--Text：" + info.getText());
                L.i(TAG, "--windowId:" + info.getWindowId());
                boolean contentInvalid = info.isVisibleToUser();
                L.i(TAG, "--contentInvalid:" + contentInvalid);

                for (int i = 0; i < info.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    AccessibilityNodeInfo child = info.getChild(i);
                    boolean equals = child.getClassName().equals("android.widget.ListView");
                    if(equals){
                        for (int j = 0; j < child.getChildCount(); j++) {
                            L.i("listview child："+j);
                            AccessibilityNodeInfo child1 = child.getChild(j);
                            if (child1 != null) {
                                if (child1.isClickable()) {
                                    L.i("listview child click");
                                    info.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK); // click
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }else{
                        if(child!=null){
                            addFriendSearch(info.getChild(i));
                        }
                    }

                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

or How to enter the event？

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In 'info' you are having the handle to the complete parent widget but you are trying to click on a specific element.
You would have to access specific child element using the 'child1' to be able to click on the specific element.

Change

```
info.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
```

to

```
child1.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
```

This will ensure the click action is performed on specific sub element and not the complete widget, which is the reason it is not working currently.